# pydbg - failed setting breakpoint at

Tags: python-2.7, hook, pydbg

I want to hook calc.exe and get its api calling information, but I get the error that Failed setting breakpoint at 01012d6c (the type of error is pydbg.pdx.pdx)when I add hook. I search so much information but failed to solve. Could anyone tell me how to do? thanks!

Comment: Please ad your code.

Comment: self.hooks.add(self.dbg, self.OEP, 0, self.oepBrakPointFunc, None). I catch the error at this position.

Comment: It is really close to impossible to get any clue on your problem without seeing *all* of your relevant code.
Best if you attempt to write here a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: After searching many solutions, I fixed it! Thanks anyway!